# Chromium based browsers and firefox are disconnecting websocket when launching tel: links

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, websocket, socket.io

I have this issue where chromium browsers and firefox are disconnecting and causing a ping timeout with my websockets(socket.io).

I'm using vue 2.7 on the frontend and node 16 on the backend

Safari doesnt do it.

I've spent hours googling about and can't find a solution for it.

Changing pingtimeout and pinginterval doesnt fix it

Anyone else having this issue or have a solution to not disconnect the socket?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.